# How to fill data to column name when after Merge dataframe using merge PANDAS?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I using python 3 and i have three dataframe:

**df1**

| PEOPLE | AMOUNT_custom_A | AMOUNT_custom_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | NaN | NaN |
| P2 | NaN | NaN |
| P3 | NaN | NaN |

**df2:**

| PEOPLE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | 1.0 |
| P2 | 1.0 |

**df3**

| PEOPLE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| P2 | 1.0 |
| P3 | 4.0 |

```
 df_1= pd.merge(df_1, df2,     on ='PEOPLE ', how ='outer') //(Step 1)
 df_1= pd.merge(df_1, df3,     on ='PEOPLE ', how ='outer') //(Step 2)
 df_1= df_1.loc[:, ~df_merge.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
```

**Ouput Actual**:

| PEOPLE | AMOUNT_custom_A | AMOUNT_custom_B | AMOUNT_X | AMOUNT_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | NaN |
| P2 | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| P3 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 4.0 |

**Question**
How to field data at (Step 1) to column AMOUNT_custom_A and field data at (Step 2) to column AMOUNT_custom_B?

**Ouput Expected**:

| PEOPLE | AMOUNT_custom_A | AMOUNT_custom_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 1.0 | NaN |
| P2 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| P3 | NaN | 4.0 |

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df['AMOUNT_custom_A'] = df['AMOUNT_custom_A'].fillna(df.pop('AMOUNT_X'))
df['AMOUNT_custom_B'] = df['AMOUNT_custom_B'].fillna(df.pop('AMOUNT_Y'))
```

If alwyas missing columns `AMOUNT_custom_A` and `AMOUNT_custom_B` first select only `PEOPLE` column for `df1` and `rename` columns names in `merge`:

```
df_1= pd.merge(df_1[['PEOPLE']], df2.rename(columns={'AMOUNT':'AMOUNT_custom_A'}), on ='PEOPLE ', how ='outer') //(Step 1)
df_1= pd.merge(df_1, df3.rename(columns={'AMOUNT':'AMOUNT_custom_B'}), on ='PEOPLE ', how ='outer') //(Step 2)
df_1= df_1.loc[:, ~df_merge.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solutions of you. Both solution active in case of me. It resolved. Have a nice day <3